# ¿Cómo ejecutar un botón desde otra acción?

Tags: html5, sql

Tengo el formulario de pago de paypal

```
<form name="form1" method="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<!-- Resto de input -->

<!-- Botón que ejecuta el direccionamiento al pago paypal-->

<input type="submit" value="paypal sandbox">

</form>
```

Pero este `input` tipo `submit` deseo ejecutarlo desde otra acción, tengo un enlace fuera del formulario (`form`) entonces lo que deseo lograr es que al dar clic en el siguiente enlace:

```
<a class="checkout" onclick="proceso(2)">Continuar</a>
```

Este ejecute la siguiente acción:

```
<input type="submit" value="paypal sandbox">
```

utilizando jQuery u otro control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la misma propiedad `onclick` y logralo de dos formas tomar las propiedad del `form` y enviar el formulario de las siguientes maneras:

```
<a class="checkout" onclick="process(2); $('form').submit();">continue</a>
```

Ahora si se tiene múltiples formularios en la misma página que deseas ejecutar la acción, puedes identificarlos utilizando diferentes selectores.

- Clase `.`
- Id `#`
- Atributo de nombre (`name`) etc.

Ejemplo con un `id` agregado al formulario = Myform1

```
<a class="checkout" onclick="process(2); $('form#Myform1').submit();">continue</a>
```

Otro ejemplo:

```
<a class="checkout" onclick="process(2); $('[name=form1]').submit();">continue</a>
```

La segunda manera es ejecutar el `submit` botón que se encuentra dentro del formulario, de la siguiente forma:

```
<a class="checkout" onclick="process(2); $('[type=submit]').trigger('click');">continue</a>
```

Te dejo dos temas relacionado al mismo en diferentes procedimientos:

- [¿Cómo puedo hacer submit usando un botón que no se encuentra dentro del formulario?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1784/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-hacer-submit-usando-un-bot%C3%B3n-que-no-se-encuentra-dentro-del-formular)
- [Otro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes darle un Id al botón de tipo submit, por ejemplo: "send".

Después, para hacer que se ejecute ese botón desde otra acción lo puedes hacer con JavaScript de la siguiente manera:

Ponle un escuchador de eventos al enlace que mencionas, que el evento que escuche sea el de "click". Para ello necesitas ponerle un Id al enlace. Luego, cuando se haga click en el enlace, haz que también se active el evento click del botón. Para poder manipular al botón también necesitas darle un Id. Por eso sugerí llamarle "send".

Debería quedarte algo similar a esto:

```js
//Con JQuery sería algo así:
$("#continue").on("click", function(e){
  //Con esta instrucción haces que se ejecute el botón que envía el formulario.
  $('#send').click();
});


//Sin JQuery así:
document.getElementById("continue").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  document.getElementById('send').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name = "form1" action = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method = "POST">
  <!-- Resto de input -->
  <!-- Botón que ejecuta el direccionamiento al pago paypal-->
  <input type = "submit" id = "send" value = "paypal sandbox">
</form>

<a class="checkout" id = "continue">Continuar</a>
```

También, la URL a la que vas a enviar los datos va en el atributo "action" del formulario. En el atributo "method" va eso, el método. Supongo que sería POST. Usa el que necesites.